# ggplot2 barplot labels using counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the code below, how do I add label to each bar showing its count? Thanks

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
ggplot(iris) +
    geom_bar(aes_string(x="Species"), fill="steelblue") +
#   geom_text(aes(label="Species")) +          # does not work
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank()
         )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data(iris)
#Plot
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_bar(aes_string(x="Species"), fill="steelblue") +
  geom_text(data= iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(N=n()),
            aes(x=Species,y=N,label=N),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

You can also try a different position for labels with this:

```
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_bar(aes_string(x="Species"), fill="steelblue") +
  geom_text(data= iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(N=n()),
            aes(x=Species,y=N,label=N),position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),vjust=-0.5)+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()
  )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have a followup question. I cannot get this to work when defined within a function `bar.plot <- function(df, y) {ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes_string(x=y)) + geom_text(data=df %>% group_by(df$y) %>% summarise(N=n()), aes(x=y, y=N, label=N))}` and called with `bar.plot(iris, "Species")`. Problem seems to be in `aes(x=y,...)`. I do not quite understand how the output of `group_by() %>% summarise()` is assigned to `aes(x=`. Any help? Thanks

Comment: You could try isolating the task like `newdf <- df %>% group_by(df$y) %>% summarise(N=n())` and then use inside `geom_text()` also check about evaluation of strings in `dplyr()` as long as it looks like the function is also giving issues because of `df$y`. `newdf` saves the results of counts and then add as labels!

Comment: `newdf <- df %>% group_by(df[y]) %>% summarise(N=n())` works, now need to figure out what to use for `x` in `geom_text(aes(x=?, y=N, label=N))`.

Comment: x should be the name you have in `df[y]`. You should check `names(newdf)` and see that details. If a weird name appears you can use `rename` and give it a specific name and then add to x in `geom_text()`

Comment: Names are showing up correct - `names(newdf)` outputs `[1] "Species" "N"`. My issue is `aes(x,y,label)` does not take string arguments, so `aes(x=names(newdf)[1], y=names(newdf)[2], label=names(newdf)[2])` does not work. I am probably missing something very basic.

Comment: It looks better if you rename the columns with standard names, then you set into geom easily! Try `newdf %>% rename(x=Species,y=N) -> newdf` and then set in as only `aes(x=x,y=y,label=y)`

Comment: Why not use this: ```geom_text(aes(x=Species, label = ..count..),stat = "count", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))```?

Comment: @AndreasM It is also a fantastic recommendation !